# MATLAB my code doesn't work

Tags: matlab

```
RGB = imread('image.jpg');
GRAY = rgb2gray(RGB);

threshold = graythresh(GRAY);
BWW = im2bw(GRAY, threshold);

BWW = bwareaopen(BWW,250);
```

**how can I let 'im' be 'BWW' for making the next lines work? 
 (how should I complete the line of 'im = '**
I tried to write BWW instead of im, but it doesn't work (because of rgb2gray).

```
im = 
im1 = rgb2gray(im);
im1 = medfilt2(im1,[15 15]);
BW = edge(im1,'sobel');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably just skip `rgb2gray(im)` and just do `im1 = medfilt2(BWW, [15 15])`. Otherwise you would be converting black&white to RGB and then to grayscale, but I think that a grayscale image contains pixel values between 0 and 1, and black&white is a grayscale image with only 0 or 1. So converting to RGB and then back to grayscale won't change the image.